# How can I calculate the following sum?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

By using a polynomial $P(x)=x^3-7x+6$ how can I calculate the sum

$S=3\times[(1\times4)+(2\times5)+(3\times6)+...+(99\times102)]$

I tried and I found $P(x)=(x+3)(x-1)(x-2)$

I see that $3(1\times4)=3(x-1)(x+2) $

Here i'm stuck.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the difference of the polynomials for natural number $n$: $P(n+1)-P(n)=(n+1)^3-n^3-7(n+1)+7n=3n^2+3n+1-7=3(n^2+n-2)=3(n+1)(n-2)$.

Now you have to sum $3\sum_{n=3}^{101}(n+1)(n-2)= \sum_{n=3}^{101}(P(n+1)-P(n))=P(102)-P(3)$ (telescope sum).